How to verify that the bunch of DTO fields has not been set?
Is it possible to verify that some fields, for example, of the DTO object is not "affected" during unit testing?
Example:
Imagine we have some DTO to sent via rest:
public class CallbackDTO {
    private Long                  id;
    private String                status;
    private Long                  checkPointId;
    private List<CallbackDetails> details;
    private OffsetDateTime        sysdate;
    // getters and setters
}
class CallbackDetails {
    private String              propertyName;
    private String              propertyValue;
    private Map<String, String> additionalProperties;
    // getters and setters
}

And i have some code that sends a two diffrent "callbacks":
public class CallbackSender {
    public CallbackDTO sendCallbackToOneSystem() {
        var callback = new CallbackDTO();
        callback.setId(1L);
        callback.setStatus("NEW");
        return callback;
    }
    public CallbackDTO sendCallbackToAnotherSystem() {
        var callback = new CallbackDTO();
        callback.setId(2L);
        callback.setStatus("FINISHED");
        callback.setSysdate(OffsetDateTime.now());
        callback.setCheckPointId(1L);
        callback.setDetails(
            List.of(
                new CallbackDetails()
                    .setPropertyName("some-property")
                    .setPropertyValue("some-value")
                    .setAdditionalProperties(
                        Map.of(
                            "request-id", UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
                            "correlation-header-name", "x-correlation-id",
                            "correlation-header-ref", "request-id"
                        )
                    )
            )
        );
        return callback;
    }
}

So, i write a unit test for method:
    @Test
    void sendCallbackToOneSystem() {
        var cs = new CallbackSender();
        var callback = cs.sendCallbackToOneSystem();
        assertEquals(1L, callback.id());
        assertEquals("NEW", callback.status());
        
        // and here I want to make sure that NO OTHER FIELDS have been "touched"/set
    }

Well, my question is how to do an assertions, that method sendCallbackToOneSystem does nothig with any fields of CallbackDTO except id and status ?
Ofcource i can assert for all possible fields for "default" values (eg null or 0 or empty etc) but may be there is a more elegant way ?

In example that you provided method has no parameters and DTO is created inside. There is no way how you can verify on what exactly happens to this object.
public DTO do() {
DTO dto = new DTO();
//Do anything
}

If you had something like this instead:
public DTO do(DTO dto) {
//Do anything
return dto;
}

You could use assertj https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-recursive-comparison-ignoring-fields
DTO input = new DTO();
DTO output = object.do(input);
assertThat(input).usingRecursiveComparison()
                    .ignoringFields("id")
                    .isEqualTo(output);



injections or constructions does not matter. even with assertj i can only assert fields has been set, but no way to assert that other fields have not been set.

@snej0keee it matters because if you construct something inside the method there is no way to verify initial state of the object before method execution, you just don't have a reference to it. On the second part of your question -> you compare initial state of the object with final state ( ignoring changed fields ). If objects are not equal, then something unexpected was changed.

of course, I can. The initial state of my DTO is new DTO(). I don't need to verify what has been changed during my method. I need to verify that the result of my method only has specific fields set. Imagine I have an DTO with 10 Integer fields. Do I know what the initial state of the object is? Of course, it is 10 nulls. Can I set one of those fields to 42 and make sure that the other 9 fields are still null? That is what im looking for.
